# Ruby Split Integer Into Array

Tags: ruby

I have this value `x = 876885` . I want to split that value into the array like `[876,885]`

This is what I tried

```
x.to_s[0..2].split(',') #=> ["876"]
```

How can I get something like `[876,885]`?

Comment: `"[876,885]"` is not an array, it is a string with leading and trailing square-brackets. Do you want an array of integers, like `[876, 885]`? What happens if the number is `76885`?

Comment: Yup. I want an array of integers like [876,885]. Thank you.

Comment: And what happens if the number is `76885`?

Comment: @theTinMan, I've no idea. I didn't consider about it.

Comment: It's probably something good to consider. Your question is ambiguous about your input and desired output. Separating an integer with commas indicates thousands, but isn't useful for much beyond a string representation of the value for human eyes. It isn't going to be returning usable values for string output if the original number was `100000` because your array will be `[100,0]`. Similarly, `1234` would be `[123,4]`. So, without better explanation your goal seems nonsensical and won't give any sort of usable/consistent output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How's about this:

```
x = 876885
x.to_s.scan(/.../).map {|e| e.to_i }
=> [876, 885]
```

Answer (score 20):

Similar to DigitalRoss's answer.

```
x.divmod(1000)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[x/1000, x%1000] # => [876, 885]
```

Comment: what is that expression called ? can you give me any doc to ?

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. Look it up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to handle numbers of arbitrary length, then you can do it using [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
876885.to_s.each_char.each_slice(3).map{|x| x.join}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
[x.to_s[0..2], x.to_s[3..-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**@DigitalRoss**'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916837/13278922) is the best for 6-digit numbers, but here's a more general one:

```
a = 876885
a.to_s.chars.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.join.to_i }

# ⇒ [
#  [0] 876,
#  [1] 885
#]
```